# Writing BLE notifty characteristic fails from uwp app

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Windows UWP app that is configured as a Peripheral, and advertises one Service with two Characteristics:

1. Outgoing messages (Notify)
2. Incoming messages (WriteWithoutResponse)

I can connect to the Peripheral Device, find the Service, subscribe, and receive messages.
I write the outgoing messages with

```
var result = await _peripheralOutgoingCharacteristic.NotifyValueAsync(dataToWrite);
```

But I can only send 8.
The ninth message fails with `A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)`

The Central still appears connected (I haven't tried to disconnect).
What could be the problem?

Comment: I have never seen and been reported about such issue but I guess that it can be because you send data too often.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko even 1 per second suffers the same problem..

Comment: Interesting. Windows 10 or 11?

Comment: Have you checked the `MaxNotificationSize` property of the GattSubscribedClient object to see the maximum notification size for a particular client?

Comment: @Roy Li - MSFT It actually should not affect the error somehow and should simple cut the data.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay Any way, tested on Win 10 IoT with Bluetooth Framework: works without any problem.

Comment: When you mentioned `you could only send 8`, you mean you could only send notification for 8 times?